# For Loop with GGplot returning only one plot instead of all plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm a novice with R so bear with me if I say something wrong or left anything out. I've been trying to create a for loop to return multiple plots based on different peoples names. The idea is to have the for loop change the name after creating the plot, then saving the plot to "plots[1], plots[2], etc". The problem I keep running into is that it only returns plots[19] and marks plots 1-18 as null. Does anyone know why plots 1-18 won't print out?

```
batters<-unique(data_all$Batter) 
battersdf<-data.frame(batters)
plots<-list()
i= 1
for (i in 19:nrow(battersdf)) {
hit_data<-subset(data_all, Batter== battersdf[i,1])
plots[[i]]<-ggplot()+
geom_path(data = hp, aes(x=x, y=y))+
coord_equal()+
geom_point(data=hit_data, aes(x=hit_data$ContactPositionZ, y = hit_data$ContactPositionX,
size = .5, color = hit_data$PlayResult))+
labs(color = "Play Result",
title = name,
subtitle = "Point of Contact (Sep 16 - Oct 2, 2022)")+
xlab("In/Out")+
ylab("Late/Out Front")

print(plots[[i]])
}
```

Comment: What happens, after the loop, when you type `plots[[1]]` into the console? It's likely that the plots just don't get displayed for long enough to see them if you are trying to show one for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Hi, it looks like all you need to change is `i in 19:nrow(battersdf)` to `i in 1:nrow(battersdf)`

Comment: @AustinGraves I used what you said and it loaded the plots into the list, however, now when I type plots[[1]] into the console it gives me a check_aesthetics() error, saying aesthetics must be either length 1 or same as the data